# Can we have relations of the same type of their composing ordered pairs?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic

Is it possible to define a binary function $P$ in the language of set theory that obeys the [characteristic property of ordered pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Generalities) and such that for any two sets $A,B$, for any definable relation $R$, there exists a set $R^*$ such that: $$R^*=\{P(a,b)| a \in A \land b \in B \land  a \ R \ b \}\land \\\forall a \in A \ \forall b \in B \\ [\exists X (X \subseteq \bigcup (R^*)\land X=P(a,b)) \leftrightarrow a \ R \ b] \ \text{?}$$

Notice that $\bigcup(R^*)$ would be able to *represent a relation* even though it is NOT a set of ordered pairs!

Using the language of type theory this way we can have a relation of type n being *composed* (i.e. is the union of) of type n ordered pairs!

> If that is possible, then what are the general properties that $P$ must fulfill in order for it to satisfy the above condition?
>
> What are known references about such subject?

Comment: What does it mean for a function to obey the ordered pair property?

Comment: It means it obey the following rule: $\forall a,b,c,d [P(a,b) = P(c,d) \to a=c \land b=d]$